# Complete quarter flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create flag for my data based at complete quarter. Something like this logic:

If passed months in quarter less than 3 then flag N else Y

Month - quarter- full quarter flag

```
10-2022, q4, y
11-2022, q4, y
12-2022, q4, y
01-2023, q1, n
02-2023, q1, n
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Any ideas with window function etc

Comment: What data type is column `Month`... please don't say string.

Comment: I tried window functions but with any working result. Month is date like 1-Nov-2022 etc, not string

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I haven't any working result or query. I tried count over partition by.

Comment: We understand its not working, else you wouldn't be asking a question :) but we always want to see what you have tried.

Comment: Is your flag based on data in the table or just the current date?

Comment: On data in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) and partition by year of the month and quarter number to get the result you want.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bdbc9/1):

```
select
    month,
    quarter,
    case when count(1) over (partition by year(month), quarter) >= 3 then 'Y' else 'n' end as full_quarter_flag
from
    data_table
```

| month | quarter | full_quarter_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | q4 | Y |
| 2022-11-01 | q4 | Y |
| 2022-12-01 | q4 | Y |
| 2023-01-01 | q1 | n |
| 2023-02-01 | q1 | n |

Comment: It works perfect. I added only customer column to partition by :)